# Error :org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed) (State=08S01,code=0)

Tags: java, hive

Our one of the Gateway machines getting a continuous error on Hive.

While we are trying to execute any(select, Insert and drop) command in a beeline, frequently getting Thrift. transport Error.

I have downloaded all hive, metastor logs and checked. we don't see any error's related to Thrifts or metadata. Please suggest to us for below errors.

Authentication is working fine.

We did not change any connection properties.

3 days before it was working fine.

[image]

Here is the link for this question: [More...](https://forum.huawei.com/enterprise/en/error-org-apache-thrift-transport-ttransportexception-java-net-socketexception-broken-pipe-write-failed-state-08s01-code-0/thread/582622-899)